# I am trying to classify text using NLTK Naive Bayes Classifier. I am getting ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python-3.x

I text cleaned and generated bi-grams. The bi-grams are displaying but I am trying to train and test text to classify using NLTK Naïve Bayes. I am getting the error shown in the title.

```
import nltk
from nltk.util import ngrams
#generating bigrams for all narratives
bigrams_all=ngrams(df,2)
#printing bigrams of one narrative
ninety_seven=df.loc[97].loc['FSR Narrative']
nine_bi=ngrams(ninety_seven,2)
print(nine_bi)
print([" ".join(t) for t in nine_bi])

# set that we'll train our classifier with
training_set = df[:1280]

# set that we'll test our classifier with
training_set = df[1280:]

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
```

the Error trace:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-745201c14989> in <module>()
    113 training_set = df[1280:]
    114 
--> 115 classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)

C:\Anaconda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\naivebayes.py in train(cls, labeled_featuresets, estimator)
    195         # Count up how many times each feature value occurred, given
    196         # the label and featurename.
--> 197         for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:
    198             label_freqdist[label] += 1
    199             for fname, fval in featureset.items():

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: *Where* are you getting the error?  Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: In the last line, edited question to show trace

Comment: What do the elements of `training_set` look like?

Comment: [1280 rows x 2 columns]
column 1 is text cleaned narratives (split into individual words, stopwords removed, etc); column 2 is what the narratives are classified as

Comment: How have you verified this?  For example, what is the actual value in `df[0]`?

Comment: Note that you assign to `training_set` twice; shouldn't be the source of *this* problem, though.

Comment: thanks, the second one was meant to be testing set... also I verified by printing the training_set; printing df[0] gives me a key error

Comment: OK, then; what is an example of an element of `df`?  `train` looks like it expects it to be a list of 2-tuples.

Comment: FTR Narrative    [ motor, chip, indication, posted, road, post, inspection, indicated, metal, chips, center, sump, isolation,  dented, mirror, equal, number, recommended, replacement, car]
Mode             [gup]

Comment: I'm not sure how I would get it to a tuple

Comment: As the code says, it needs to be a featureset for the first element, and a label for the second.

Comment: how would you recommend doing that

Comment: Isn't column 1 the feature set, and column 2 the classification/label?

Comment: @ScottHunter yes it is